# Find value in column and output in adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with my code. If it were to work, it would scan through a column and if it finds specific keywords (`"Costco", "Dominos", etc`), it would output in the adjacent cell. **However, there's an error prompt as soon as it encounters a cell without the first keyword ("Costco")**. If it would be possible to fix this code, I'd be grateful.

Otherwise, I'd like to keep the `Case` structure as I may be adding more keywords and **for the "search" not to be case-sensitive**.

Here below is my code:

```
Sub FindAndOutput()

Dim Col As Range
Dim FirstRow As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range

Set Col = Application.InputBox("Select Column", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)
Set FirstRow = Application.InputBox("Select FIrst Row", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)

Set WorkRng = Range(Cells(FirstRow.Row, Col.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, Col.Column).End(xlUp).Row, Col.Column))

For Each rng In WorkRng

Select Case True

Case rng.Find("Costco") <> ""
Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1) = "Costco"

Case rng.Find("Dominos") <> ""
Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1) = "Dominos"

Case Else
Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Interior.Color = 12309

End Select
Next
End Sub
```

And a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

Comment: `Range.Find()` returns a `Range` object or `Nothing` - you cannot compare `Nothing` with "" Maybe try   `Case rng.Value Like "*Costco*"` or `Instr(rng.Value,"Costco")>0`

Comment: I already knew about `InStr` but I kept this solution for last as it's case-sensitive. Beyond that, I thought `Range.Find()` returned the value of the cell containing the keyword; at least that was what I saw when I tried `MsgBox Range("A2").Find("Costco")`. Finally, why are `*`s required before the first and after the last letter of "Costco"? @TimWilliams

Comment: InStr is (by default) case-sensitive (vbBinaryCompare). You can make it case-insensitive by adding the vbCompareMode:=vbTextCompare argument.

Comment: `InStr()` can be used either way - case-sensitive or case-insensitive (using vbTextCompare).  Using `Like` requires wildcards to match part of a string

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for letting me know, I'll use `InStr()` then to save a few lines of code.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for the insight. Will use the argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub FindAndOutput()

Dim Col As Range
Dim FirstRow As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range

Set Col = Application.InputBox("Select Column", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)
Set FirstRow = Application.InputBox("Select FIrst Row", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)

Set WorkRng = Range(Cells(FirstRow.Row, Col.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, Col.Column).End(xlUp).Row, Col.Column))

For Each rng In WorkRng

Select Case True

Case InStr(1, rng.Value, "Costco", 1) > 0
Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1) = "Costco"

'Other Keywords

Case Else
Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Interior.Color = 65535

End Select
Next
End Sub
```