# Search through hundreds of keywords within column and and output keyword in offset cell

Tags: vba, excel

*In relation to this question: [Find value in column and output in adjacent cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689496/find-value-in-column-and-output-in-adjacent-cell)*

Currently, I'm using a `Select Case True` structure with a `InStr` function to search for cells in a column matching keywords(`"Costco", etc`) and then outputting those keywords in offset cells. Additionally, the cells without these keywords are highlighted and the search isn't case sensitive. See code below:

```
Sub FindAndOutput()

Dim Col As Range
Dim FirstRow As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range

Set Col = Application.InputBox("Select Column", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)
Set FirstRow = Application.InputBox("Select FIrst Row", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)

Set WorkRng = Range(Cells(FirstRow.Row, Col.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, Col.Column).End(xlUp).Row, Col.Column))

For Each rng In WorkRng

Select Case True

Case InStr(1, rng.Value, "Costco", 1) > 0
Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1) = "Costco"

'Other Keywords

Case Else
Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Interior.Color = 65535

End Select
Next
End Sub
```

**I've been wondering which approach with VBA is best (lowest execution time and less code to write) for this procedure when, rather than having a few keywords to search through, I have hundreds.**

Should I use an `array`? If so, have I correctly written this code below?

```
Sub FindVendorAndOutputVendor()

Dim Col As Range
Dim FirstRow As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Vendor As Variant

Set Vendor = Array("Costco", "Walmart") 'Add more vendors

Set Col = Application.InputBox("Select Column", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)
Set FirstRow = Application.InputBox("Select FIrst Row", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)

Set WorkRng = Range(Cells(FirstRow.Row, Col.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, Col.Column).End(xlUp).Row, Col.Column))

For Each rng In WorkRng

    If InStr(1, rng.Value, Vendor, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1) = Vendor

    Else
    Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Interior.Color = 65535

        End If

            Next
End Sub
```

Should I use a dictionary? If so, can someone guide me?
Should I stick to the `Select Case True` structure?

Finally, if none of the partial solutions I've proposed is best, what is, then?

Comment: An array probably would be your best bet, but you've kind of got the idea backwards. What you want to do is grab the `WorkRng` as an array so that you can loop through memory instead of through the sheet http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an Array with another loop and an IF statement to compare.  The `Select Case` method would be hard coded I presume, which I always tend to avoid.  Following @Marcucciboy's point...this is how to do it:

```
Dim Rng As Range, WorkRng As Range
Dim Vendor As Variant
Dim vData 'As Variant
Dim vDataVendor 'As Variant
Dim rngHighlight As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Vendor = Array("Costco", "Walmart")
    vData = WorkRng.Value2
    vDataVendor = WorkRng.Offset(0, 1).Value2

    For i = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
        ' Loop through, looking for a Vendor that matches
        For j = LBound(Vendor) To UBound(Vendor)
            If InStr(1, vData(i, 1), Vendor(j), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                vDataVendor(i, 1) = Vendor(j)
                ' Exit the loop, limiting it to only one vendor
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        ' If None of the Vendors ware found, then add the cell to the Highlight range.
        If j > UBound(Vendor) Then
            If rngHighlight Is Nothing Then
                Set rngHighlight = WorkRng(i)
            Else
                Set rngHighlight = Union(rngHighlight, WorkRng(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    WorkRng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(vData) - LBound(vData) + 1, 1) = vDataVendor
    If Not rngHighlight Is Nothing Then rngHighlight.Interior.Color = 65535
```

Note how I setup a range of cells to highlight, instead of doing each as you find them.  This will also speed up the routine, as any/all interactions with the worksheet/cells are slow.  You'd be hard pressed to find something faster then this.

Comment: `You'd be hard pressed to find something faster then this.` Not to belittle @AdamsTips 's answer using a collection, but if speed is key, should I indeed favor your code over his? Sorry, I don't know the pros and cons of arrays and collections.

Comment: This is a great example using arrays, and especially the part of setting the color property once for the entire range, rather than individually on each cell. In my experience, that is where you are going to have the biggest performance improvements. Every time you access or modify a property in the Excel object model you are going to have a performance hit. @Profex demonstrates how you can do this once instead of hundreds or thousands of times.

Comment: Regarding collections vs. arrays, there are other questions that address this in more detail, but practically speaking, the speed difference is very little unless you are dealing with hundreds of thousands or millions of iterations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740862/code-optimisation-arrays-vs-collections

Comment: @AdamsTips I'll remember to define the entire range on which I need modify properties rather than individually modifying each cells within that range. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use VBA, but I wonder if it would be easier to just use a formula right in Excel... Then you could just use conditional formatting to highlight your cells. See: [Excel: Search for a list of strings within a particular string using array formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313919/excel-search-for-a-list-of-strings-within-a-particular-string-using-array-formu)

If the store name column is an exact match to the list of store names you are searching for, then you could just use the simpler `VLookup()` function in Excel.

As to running this process in VBA as described in the original question, you can also use a collection object. I find this to be just a little more readable and easy to understand than arrays, but that's more of a personal preference.

```
Public Sub Example()

    Const strSearch As String = "The Costco Store"
    Dim colWords As New Collection
    Dim varWord As Variant

    With colWords
        ' Load words (You could also load these from a spreadsheet)
        .Add "Walmart"
        .Add "Costco"
        .Add "Target"

        ' Loop through words, searching for match
        For Each varWord In colWords
            If strSearch Like "*" & varWord & "*" Then
                ' Found match
                ' Highlight cell, display text, etc...
                Debug.Print varWord
                ' Exit the loop, since we already found a match.
                Exit For
            End If
        Next varWord
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: No, it isn't an exact match and that's why Vlookup isn't an option. As for using a formula, wouldn't that be near impossible to load into cells, given how many keywords I'll be adding into it? Finally, I really like the "readable" aspect of your code but how much time am I compromising when using collections rather than arrays?